# Why is it so hard to compute $\pi_n(S^n)$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Of course it isn't really that hard - nowhere near as hard as $\pi_k(S^n)$ for $k>n$, for instance. The hardness that I'm referring to is based on the observation that apparently nobody knows how to do the calculation within the homotopy category of topological spaces. Approaches that I'm aware of include:

-Homology theory (the Hurewicz theorem)

-Degree theory

-The divergence theorem

and each of these reduces to a calculation within some other category (PL or Diff).  My question is: is there something "wrong" with hTop that precludes a computation of $\pi_n(S^n)$ within that category?

Certainly if my assumption that such a proof does not exist is wrong, I would be very interested to know it.

---

I have been thinking and reading further about this question for the past couple days, and I wanted to summarize some of the main points in the answers and questions:

1. Some techniques - e.g. the Freudenthal Suspension Theorem via the James construction or the Hurewicz Theorem with singular homology - might actually lead to proofs without any approximation arguments.  But so far I'm not sure we quite have it: the proof of the Freudenthal Suspension Theorem uses the fact that $J(X)$ is homotopy equivalent to the loop space of the suspension of $X$, but the only proofs I can find of this fact use a CW structure on $X$, and similarly for the proofs of the Hurewicz theorem.  Can these results be proved for the sphere without PL or smooth approximation?
2. Perhaps this question is entirely wrong-headed: the techniques of PL and smooth approximation are very well adapted to homotopy theory, so why try to replace them with a language which may end up adding more complications with little additional insight?  Fair enough.  But the goal of this question is not to disparage or seek alternatives to existing techniques, it is to understand exactly what role they play in the theory.  The statement "The identity map $S^n \to S^n$ is homotopically nontrivial and freely generates $\pi_n(S^n)$" makes no mention of CW complexes or smooth structures, yet apparently the statement is difficult or impossible to prove without that sort of language (except in the case $n=1$!)  To seek an understanding of this observation is different from lamenting it.

Comment: One option which is perhaps overkill is to use the Hopf fibration to show that pi_2(S^2) is Z and then to use Freudenthal suspension theorem (which can be proved with homotopy theoretic ideas e.g. the James construction).

Comment: @CallanMcGill This is a nice idea, but the only proofs that the Hopf fibration is homotopically nontrivial that I know either use the nontriviality of $\pi_2(S^2)$, the Gysin sequence (and hence (co)homology theory), or differential forms.  In fact, I first started thinking about this question when I realized that I don't know a purely homotopy theoretic way to prove that the Hopf fibration is a generator for $\pi_3(S^2)$.

Comment: @PaulSiegel What about Hopf's original proof  http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/hopf.pdf

Comment: @PaulSiegel By your definition of "hard", is there a non-hard computation of $\pi_k(S^n)$ for $k<n$?

Comment: @DimitriChikhladze I haven't read Hopf's original paper (I don't read German).  From what I understand, he deduced the nontriviality of the Hopf fibration from the fact that all of the fibers are linked; the only way I personally would know how to do this is using calculus.  If Hopf's argument is more fundamental than this, let me know.

Comment: @CharlesRezk I believe Hatcher has a non-hard argument in the case $k=1$, and I seem to remember another textbook which adapts Hatcher's argument to any $k < n$, but I can't find a reference at the moment.  It may have used the Freudenthal suspension theorem, which has non-hard proofs as Callan McGill pointed out.

Comment: @PaulSiegel The proof I know involves approximating any map by a PL map, which would seem to count as hard.

Comment: I'm sure someone here has read Hopf's paper. I haven't myself, and I don't read German so well to go through it quickly and get details. But anyway from today's perspective the methods used are elementary. This brings us to the question of what exactly is meant by being hard in your question.

Comment: I agree that the thing is sort of hard. Freudenthal suspension theorem is also not trivial. But definitely it can be done without too much trouble in the spirit of Hopf's paper from 1930.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but how is homology outside of the homotopy category of topological spaces?

Comment: Probably, to check nontriviality of the Hopf bundle one can compute its Euler class?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you proved that the $n$-th homotopy group of the $n$-sphere was the integers in a formalism internal to the homotopy category, do you feel something would be gained?  I suppose my first inclination would be to be suspicious that the argument is simply a re-encoding of one of the more basic proofs you've already cited.

Comment: @RyanBudney A question in a similar spirit would be "Why is it so hard to solve differential equations within the language of rational numbers?"  The point is not that solving differential equations over $\mathbb{Q}$ is desirable even if it's possible; rather, it is useful to understand the "defect" in $\mathbb{Q}$ which makes the theory differential equations such a mess (namely, the failure of completeness).

Comment: @DenisNardin I would argue that singular homology does indeed live within hTop, but so far as I know one has to leave hTop to calculate any nontrivial examples, say by using PL or smooth approximations.  I would never argue that these techniques are *bad*, but I do feel that their necessity deserves to be explained.

Comment: @PaulSiegel To compute $H_n(S^n)$ I would prove the suspension isomorphism in homology (that uses only homotopy invariance and Mayer-Vietoris) and then proceed to compute $H_0(S^0)$, which is elementary. I think that this proof does not leave the homotopy category, unless you regard the subdivision isomorphism to prove excision as "PL approximation"

Comment: @PaulSiegel I must admit to being slightly confused by the question. Most early calculations of $\pi_n(S^n)$ do rely heavily on hard manipulations with homotopies to reduce to continuous maps of nice forms, but the _definition_ of hTop is in terms of such homotopies. Without some of these basic tools under our control, we have almost no way to distinguish hTop from an arbitrary category.

Comment: If you like, though, one defect in hTop is that has no categorical niceties. You can't really build new objects out of old ones or use that many elementary "building block" calculations to get larger calculations. Several decades of experience with this have resulted in a working methodology where, even if a homotopy category is our goal, it almost always comes accompanied with a "chart" (like the category of spaces, or CW-complexes, or simplicial sets, or...) where all the important constructions can be carried out; the homotopy category is just a place to examine the results.

Comment: @PaulSiegel: Isn't there a simple answer?  Nobody would expect rational numbers to be a language for differential equations once they've seen things like logarithms and exponentials.  I suppose I don't see a homotopy category as a language for homotopy theory so I'm stuck without an understanding of *why* one might have that desire. I usually expect people choose their language based on what they *do* and *need* to accomplish things rather than on ideology.

Comment: I'm at a loss as to what sort of answer you're looking for, but it is funny to contemplate what $\pi_n(S^n)$ would look like if it weren't $\mathbb{Z}$. There is a ring structure coming from composition of maps, which would make $\pi_n(X)$ into a module over this ring for any $X$. But if this ring is not $\mathbb{Z}$, it's hard to envision how one may use this to arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: I don't think your question is wrong-headed at all.  Maybe it points at a difference in perspective though.  I suppose I see category theory's role in topology as a language for encoding various constructions.   You can do a lot of topology using that language, but it isn't a substitute for actually working directly with spaces.  Moreover, if you restrict yourself to a category-theoretic diet, you may very well find yourself off in a rather polarized and extreme corner of the world, cutting yourself off from more natural ways of doing things. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: Regarding one of your recent points of summary: "The statement "..." makes no mention of CW complexes or smooth structures, yet apparently the statement is difficult or impossible to prove without that sort of language." This seems more of a summary of mathematics as a whole, than about any particular theorem of topology. Many are the theorems stated in the simplest of language which require reams of new mathematical language for their proof. Much more extreme than your question are the examples of Fermat's Last Theorem or of the Poincare Conjecture, regarded now as triumphs of modern math.

Comment: @LeeMosher In both of your examples - and many others - the hardness can be explained: Fermat's last theorem is hard because it's hard to determine whether or not elliptic curves have rational points, and the Poincare conjecture is hard because the s-cobordism theorem is hard (and either open or false in dimension $<5$).  But it is not clear to me that the hardness of $\pi_n(S^n) = \mathbb{Z}$ has been explained (though I am starting to suspect that the answer might be something like "because the Freudenthal suspension theorem is hard").

Comment: So in the spectrum of theorems whose proofs use language that their statements do not use, my two examples are explained away because they are very far from some boundary. Could you give an example of a theorem that is as close to the boundary as your $\pi_n(S_n)$ question, but on the opposite side of that boundary? That might help clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 27):

I suppose that the proof that $\pi_1(S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ using covering spaces  is homotopy-theoretic.

The Freudenthal Suspension Theorem (via the James construction) tells us that 
$\Sigma: \pi_n(S^n)\to \pi_{n+1}(S^{n+1})$ is an isomorphism for $n \geq 2$ and surjective for $n =1$.

Since $S^1$ is an H-space, the suspension map $\sigma: S^1\to \Omega\Sigma S^1$ has a retraction $r: \Omega\Sigma S^1\to S^1$.  Therefore $\Sigma = \sigma_*: \pi_1(S^1)\to \pi_{2}(S^{2})$ is injective (in addition to being surjection).

Now Freudenthal completes the calculation.

Note that we don't just get an abstract isomorphism, we get that these groups are generated by $[\mathrm{id}_{S^n}]$.

---

EDIT:  Regarding getting the James Construction homotopically:  the paper

> Fantham, Peter; James, Ioan(4-OX); Mather, Michael On the reduced
>   product construction. (English summary)  Canad. Math. Bull. 39 (1996),
>   no. 4, 385–389.

derives the relevant properties using the Cube Theorems (which are about the mixing of homotopy pushouts and homotopy pullbakcs) of an earlier paper of Mather's.

Answer (score 25):

Even when computing $\pi_k(S^n), k < n$ all of the hard work, as far as I can tell, comes from showing that continuous maps behave reasonably up to homotopy; there is no difficulty once you show, whatever way you like (simplicial approximation, smooth approximation, etc.), that you can ignore space-filling curves. Until you know that it's necessary to consider the possibility that continuous maps behave in totally ungeometric ways that make them unsuitable for modeling homotopy theory.

Topological spaces and continuous maps are both absurdly general objects, and in fact too general to model homotopy theory: instead of working with the homotopy category of topological spaces we should of course be working with the homotopy category of CW complexes, and of course there are other ways to describe the homotopy category that don't involve topological spaces at all. In some of these descriptions (starting from simplicial sets, I would guess) it may be quite easy to compute $\pi_k(S^n), k \le n$.

Morally this computation should be easy starting from a heuristic picture of $\infty$-groupoids: $S^n$ is the free $\infty$-groupoid on an $n$-morphism, and in particular has no interesting $k$-morphisms for $k < n$. For $k = n$, again heuristically, all you can do starting from an $n$-morphism is compose it with itself a lot; the $\mathbb{Z}$ appearing here is the free group on one generator. Possibly this is the sort of reasoning that homotopy type theory is supposed to make precise.

---

**Edit:** That heuristic reasoning above may not seem too convincing because it doesn't seem to say anything about the higher homotopy groups, so let me spell out what it suggests about $\pi_3(S^2)$.

To compute this it suffices to ask what the free $3$-groupoid on a $2$-morphism is. A $3$-category with one object and one $1$-morphism is precisely a braided monoidal category, so the question now is what the free grouplike braided monoidal groupoid on an object $X$ is like. Well, it has a dual $X^{\ast}$ (which must in fact be its inverse) and there are unit and counit maps $1 \to X \otimes X^{\ast}, X^{\ast} \otimes X \to 1$. Finally there is a braiding $X \otimes X^{\ast} \to X^{\ast} \otimes X$. These three maps can be composed, and we get a map $1 \to 1$ which in no way is required to be the identity; in fact it can be identified with the generator of $\pi_3(S^2)$.

Incidentally, the corresponding argument for $\pi_2(S^1)$ fails because we don't have a braiding; the corresponding question is what the free grouplike monoidal groupoid on an object is like. The key is to be extremely careful what the unit and counit look like in a monoidal category which is not assumed to be symmetric, and once we are, the argument correctly suggests that $\pi_2(S^1)$ is trivial.

**Edit #2:** And the Freudenthal suspension theorem appears here in the fact that for $\pi_{n+1}(S^n), n \ge 3$ the question stabilizes to looking at the free grouplike symmetric monoidal groupoid on an object.

Comment: My question (which I may not be able to pose very well) is: what demands does your heuristic picture place on the underlying category of spaces?  Where would the heuristic run aground if nobody had ever invented CW complexes or simplicial sets and we were forced to contend with space filling curves?

Comment: @Paul: the specific heuristic argument I wrote down above requires more or less that there be a nerve / geometric realization functor $X \mapsto |X|$ from $n$-groupoids to spaces and that this functor have the property that $\pi_k(|X|, x)$ is the automorphism group of the identity automorphism of the identity... of $x$ in $X$. The simplest version of this demand is that we should be able to create Eilenberg-MacLane spaces, although that isn't enough to run the heuristic argument.

Comment: In other words I'm taking for granted that the homotopy hypothesis provides the correct model-independent description of homotopy theory and that everything else is the quest for usable models, which may or may not involve topological spaces.

Answer (score 10):

This example and many other illustrate that geometric arguments  cannot always be completely replaced by algebraic ones, much like the fundamental theorem of algebra  does not seem to have a  simple purely algebraic proof. (I'm out on a limb with this statement.)

It looks to me that a large part of  the fundamental  functors  of algebraic topology have a geometric origin; think homotopy, (co)homology, cobordism, $K$-theory.  I cannot  imagine formal arguments, devoid of geometric intuition leading to such concepts.  Obviously geometric arguments alone  cannot get you very far; think homotopy, (co)homology, cobordism theory, $K$-theory without long exact  or spectral sequences.

Being a mathematical "mutt" myself, I always favor impure arguments. They give me the comforting feeling of  not being isolated.  Also, they broaden  my sources of inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

One can show that $\Omega^n S^n$ is the group completion of the configuration space of distinct unordered particles in $R^n$. Now $\pi_0$ of this configuration space is the natural numbers. This shows that $\pi_0(\Omega^n S^n)$ is the Grothendieck group of the natural number. Thus, $Z=\pi_0(\Omega^n S^n)=\pi_n(S^n)$.

Comment: The arguments I've seen for this would fail the "internal to the homotopy category" criterion.